# Azure Cloudstorage for PHP - error in the call function createBlobService()

Tags: php, azure, upload, cloud

I have a problem that after this part of code, my program isn't working.

```
$blobRestProxy->createBlobService($connectionString);
```

`$connectionString` is good, but after some debugging I found the problem in the function `createBlobService()`, which can be found in `ServicesBuilder.php`

Problem is exactly in this part:

```
$authFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(
     $this->blobAuthenticationScheme(
          $settings->getName(),
          $settings->getKey()
      )
 );
```

Maybe I didn't do something or install something.

But I don't know how to solve it, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

What the error message your application thrown? Per your description, the problem point out the `account name` and `account key` in the code, you can build a test code script on local to check whether the `connectionString` is right.

You can get the php sample at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php-samples/blob/master/storage/BlockBlobExample.php.

And the `StorageConnectionString` should be the format in `'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=your_account_name;AccountKey=your_account_key'`

Comment: All code after $blobRestProxy->createBlobService($connectionString); isnt being proceed. There are no error messages

Comment: can you run the sample with your Azure Storage account?

Comment: We have it on our own server.

Comment: I mean, can you have a simple test via the php test sample on the link I posted, to check your Storage account is correct. If you don't have an Azure Storage account, you can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-create-storage-account/ to create an account.

Comment: I think that there is problem not with my code, but problem with our server settings, i manually install pear package, but can i check if there is running some needed service or something else what is needed for PHP running smoothly? Thanks

Comment: To implement Azure SDK in PHP, you can simply clone the SDK repo at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php, and the SDK is the folder named `WindowsAzure`, you can include the SDK in your PHP code, e.g. `require_once 'WindowsAzure/WindowsAzure.php';`. All requirements to run with Azure Service are all in the SDK folder already.

Comment: yes, i am using it, and i have also installed pear packages which are needed, but i have still the same problem...

Comment: OK, it is strange, is it convenient of you to provide your problem code snippet for me to reproduce your issue

Comment: Thanks for your patience, but i try to use another SDK for azure, and it works... this helps me http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/07/08/accessing-windows-azure-blob-storage-from-php.aspx

Comment: the SDK shows in this post is linked to the Github repo as I posted at the comment. And you can fork it at github for any update in SDK. Congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to autoload GuzzleHttp, because AuthenticationFilter.php needs it. It works for me.

```
namespace MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\Filters;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\Resources;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\IServiceFilter;
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Common\Internal\HttpFormatter;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7;
```

Comment: I can't understand whether this is an answer, or a request for help (which, in case, should be posted as another question). Which is it?